# How to retrieve number of components added to JMenu?

Tags: java, swing, junit, assert

I've done a small test and in the second test I get an assertion error (0 instead of 1):

```
package tests;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MenuTest {

    @Test
    public void testElementsAddition() {
        JMenuItem mItem1 = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem mItem2 = new JMenuItem();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu();

        mItem1.add(mItem2);
        assertEquals(1, mItem1.getComponentCount());

        menu.add(mItem1);
        assertEquals(1, menu.getComponentCount());
    }
}
```

Any Ideas why this might happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This occurs because the menu item isn't actually added to the `JMenu` itself, but is added to a popup menu internally, there is actually nothing added to the menu.

I think you will want to use [`JMenu#getItemCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#getItemCount%28%29), which *"Returns the number of items on the menu, including separators"* or, preferably, [JMenu#getMenuComponentCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#getMenuComponentCount%28%29)

Comment: Thanks, I've never came across such a mechanism.